# How to get all values in a Join with SQL server?

Tags: sql-server

I have a table that gives the sum of value per client, what I want is to make a report for sales by month by client, but there are clients that didn't buy anything in a certain month, even though I want them to appear with 0 value to compare with the present month.

```
  ;with Months AS
(SELECT 1 AS MonthNum
UNION ALL
SELECT MonthNum + 1 as MonthNum FROM Months WHERE MonthNum <12)
 select c.client_id,Months.MonthNum 'Mês2021', sum(sales) 'v' from fact_table as c cross join Months
 where Months.MonthNum=month(c.date)
 and year(c.date)=2021 group by c.intCodEntidade,Months.MonthNum order by c.client_id,Months.MonthNum
```

But it doesn't return the null values I want, instead it filters and doesn't show null's.

Please heelp.

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: You should join to "customers" table too. If you only join to fact_table, that I guess it's just the sales table, the customers that have not bought, will not appear.

Comment: Pet peeve: The semi colon  (`;`) is a statement **terminator**. It goes at the end of *all* your statements, not the *start* of statements that require the **previous** statement to be properly terminated.

Answer (score 1):

You do not explain very well, but let's suppose this is your minimal reproductible example:

```
declare @fact_table as table (
    [date] datetime,
    client_id int,
    sales money
)

insert into @fact_table values ('26/09/21', 1, 10)
insert into @fact_table values ('26/10/21', 1, 15)

 ;with Months AS
(SELECT 1 AS MonthNum
UNION ALL
SELECT MonthNum + 1 as MonthNum FROM Months WHERE MonthNum <12)
 select c.client_id,Months.MonthNum 'Mês2021', sum(sales) 'v' from @fact_table as c cross join Months
 where Months.MonthNum=month(c.date)
 and year(c.date)=2021 
 group by c.client_id,Months.MonthNum
 order by c.client_id,Months.MonthNum
```

The result (which is wrong for you) is:
client_id   | Mês2021     | v
----------- | ----------- | ---------------------
1           | 9           | 10,00
1           | 10          | 15,00

And you want that all the clients appear all the months. Is it? If so, maybe the solution to your problem is to join "Clients" table too:

```
declare @fact_table as table (
    [date] datetime,
    client_id int,
    sales money
)

declare @clients as table (
    client_id int
)

insert into @fact_table values ('26/09/21', 1, 10)
insert into @fact_table values ('26/10/21', 2, 15)

insert into @clients values (1)
insert into @clients values (2)

 ;with Months AS
(SELECT 1 AS MonthNum
UNION ALL
SELECT MonthNum + 1 as MonthNum FROM Months WHERE MonthNum <12)
 select l.client_id,m.MonthNum 'Mês2021', isnull(sum(sales),0) 'v' 
 from @clients l cross join Months m
 left join @fact_table c
 on l.client_id = c.client_id and m.MonthNum=month(c.date) and year(c.date)=2021
 group by l.client_id,m.MonthNum
 order by l.client_id,m.MonthNum
```

It would return this:

| client_id | Mês2021 | v |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 0,00 |
| 1 | 2 | 0,00 |
| 1 | 3 | 0,00 |
| 1 | 4 | 0,00 |
| 1 | 5 | 0,00 |
| 1 | 6 | 0,00 |
| 1 | 7 | 0,00 |
| 1 | 8 | 0,00 |
| 1 | 9 | 10,00 |
| 1 | 10 | 0,00 |
| 1 | 11 | 0,00 |
| 1 | 12 | 0,00 |
| 2 | 1 | 0,00 |
| 2 | 2 | 0,00 |
| 2 | 3 | 0,00 |
| 2 | 4 | 0,00 |
| 2 | 5 | 0,00 |
| 2 | 6 | 0,00 |
| 2 | 7 | 0,00 |
| 2 | 8 | 0,00 |
| 2 | 9 | 0,00 |
| 2 | 10 | 15,00 |
| 2 | 11 | 0,00 |
| 2 | 12 | 0,00 |

Is this what you wanted?

If you do not have a Clients table you could even do this:

```
 ;with Months AS
(SELECT 1 AS MonthNum
UNION ALL
SELECT MonthNum + 1 as MonthNum FROM Months WHERE MonthNum <12)
 select l.client_id,m.MonthNum 'Mês2021', isnull(sum(sales),0) 'v' 
 from (select distinct(client_id) from fact_table) l cross join Months m
 left join fact_table c
 on l.client_id = c.client_id and m.MonthNum=month(c.date) and year(c.date)=2021
 group by l.client_id,m.MonthNum
 order by l.client_id,m.MonthNum
```

Comment: YES! Thanks, I'm new to this, sometimes it's difficult to express my problem! Anyway thank you!

Comment: @CarloParodi if it solved your problem, do not forget to mark it as accepted answer (and optionally upvote it).